# Compute Aggregations before running Filter Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a simple scenario:

1. I search for some text, and elastic returns documents and
   aggregations.
2. I then filter that search with values in the fields returned from    that  aggregations. I'm using a Terms Query inside a filter
3. I want the documents to be filtered by my filter conditions, which is working fine.
4. But I want the aggregation buckets without applying the filter condition (because if I get the buckets after applying the filter, I'll just get that one value)
5. My workaround to get the aggregations without applying filters: Send two request to Elastic search, In first request, Send the query with filters applied,and in second request, Send the query without filters applied

**Question:** Is there a better way to achieve this? I looked around SO and I guess I can set `global:{}` while defining aggregations, but I'm not sure!

Or better put, Is there a way I can get aggregation results before filters are applied to a document?

## EDIT

---

I did some searching and it looks that `post_filter` was designed for cases like this, i.e., if you don't want your filter to affect aggregations. But, there was also massive talks of performance of `post_filter`

Now I wonder if sending two requests is better than using post_filter in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think post_filter performance is not as bad as you are saying. It just applies a filter on search results post aggregation. So all docs have to pass through this filter. I think you should go with post_filter because-

1. It will save you network round trip, so you will have minimal latency.
2. Will save your ES overhead of allocating resources for handling new request.
3. Your needs for post_filtered search and aggregation will be fulfilled by same set of documents, so most of the values it needs will already be in main memory or cache memory (things like doc_values)

So, performance should not get effected to much. You can also do profiling and analyse it yourself.